# Correlations in nested dataset

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis

My main objective is to perform a correlation between a fitness cost (ex: lag phase duration) and amount of resistance. I do, however, have a quite complicated data set. I performed evolution experiments with multiple replicates (further termed Evo_ID), each challenged with a different antibiotic. I then, characterised select evolved material, resulting in a data set looking like this:

[image]

I have 20 clones (Colony) isolated from a well (Evo_ID). Then, each Evo_ID was exposed to different component antibiotics (component_ab), with every component_ab having 3 Evo_ID, and each component_ab belongs to an over-arching treatment_type which includes drug cycles or drug combinations. I know that I cannot perform a simple Spearman correlation between these, as the colonies within a well, and the wells within a component_ab and the component_ab within a treatment_type should theoretically be similar to each other, and thus the data is non-independent. But if anyone could point me in the right direction of a test I could perform to get a correlation between the relative lag phase duration (in data referred to as rel_lambda) and Multidrug resistance (termed mdr_coef in the data frame).

Comment: You probably want to look at regression models. Specifically mixed models (a.k.a mixed effects models, or hierarchical models). I see you have tagged your question with this, so perhaps you are already familiar with them.

Comment: I find your description a bit hard to follow, so I'll refrain from proposing a specific model.

Comment: Pearson / Spearman correlation has no assumptions on independence, so that is not an issue if you are worried.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I realised that I would need to do some mixed effects models, but I am not sure how to get a correlation out of them. I have performed some mixed models in the past when looking at how different antibiotic therapies compare in terms of growth inhibition/extinction efficacies, but could you briefly explain how to get a correlation out of these?